# How do I turn off settings sync in GitHub codespaces before opening the codespace?

Tags: github

My settings are messed up and I want to them them off and launch a codespace without them. But if I open a codespace it opens the same settings, and then the vs code is so messed up (in a mobile browser) that I can’t press the button to turn settings sync off. Is there any way to launch a codespace without settings sync to begin with?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?